# Is there a way to detect incoming Skype calls?

Tags: c#, skype

I am working on an app that I would like to detect when the main Skype app receives a call.

Is there some way to monitor Skype and detect when there is an incoming call?

Answer (score 0):

skype4com is still a thing (at least I have seen official skype rep's respond on its usage earlier this year), its available for download and is still semi-supported. As far as I know you can use skype4com (C#) to connect to skype and read the call status etc. Some features of skype4com have been deprecated but as far as I know, call status isn't one of them

[Latest Skype4COM (Direct Download)](http://www.pcdust.com/Downloads/Skype/latest/Skype4COM.dll)